# Registration successful but does not write information into database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having this problem, that registration is successful, but it does not write the information into database.. Why?

REGISTRATION PROCESS CODE:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';

$error_msg = "";

if (isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['p'])) {
    // Sanitize and validate the data passed in
    $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Not a valid email
        $error_msg .= '<p class="error">The email address you entered is not valid</p>';
    }


    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'p', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    // Username validity and password validity have been checked client side.
    // This should should be adequate as nobody gains any advantage from
    // breaking these rules.
    //

    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

   // check existing email  
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

       if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this email address already exists.</p>';
}
$stmt->close();
    }
    // check existing username
    $prep_stmt = "SELECT id FROM members WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

                if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
    $error_msg .= '<p class="error">A user with this username  already exists.</p>';
}

$stmt->close();
    }

    // TODO: 
    // We'll also have to account for the situation where the user doesn't have
    // rights to do registration, by checking what type of user is attempting to
    // perform the operation.

    if (empty($error_msg)) {

        // Create salted password 
        $passwordHash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        // Insert the new user into the database 
        if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO  members (username, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
  $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', '$username', '$email', '$passwordHash');
            // Execute the prepared query.
            if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
                header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: INSERT');
            }
        }
        header('Location: ./continue.php');
    }
}
```

Registration Form :

```
<div class="register-form">
    <center><h2>Registration</h2></center>
        <form action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" 
                method="post" 
                name="registration_form">
            <center><p></p><input type='text' 
                name='username' 
                placeholder="Username"
                id='username' /><br></center>
            <center><p></p><input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" /><br></center>
            <center><p></p><input type="password"
                             name="password"
                             placeholder="Insert Password" 
                             id="password"/><br></center>
            <center><p></p><input type="password" 
                                     name="confirmpwd" 
                                     placeholder="Repeat Password"
                                     id="confirmpwd" /><br></center>
            <center><p></p><input type="submit" class="button"
                   value="Register" 
                   onclick="return regformhash(this.form,
                                   this.form.username,
                                   this.form.email,
                                   this.form.password,
                                   this.form.confirmpwd);" /> </center>
        </form>
        </div>
```

It did work last time, but now it does not because the server has an internal error, so I had to reupload all files and also to create a new database. I rewrote the database name and pass, and all the things there should be, so it connects to the correct database but it does not write information into that db while registration.

Comment: Add some error checking to the MySQLi bits and/or check the error logs.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - How to do that error checking?

Comment: [Start here.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: `$insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', '$username', '$email', '$passwordHash');` You should remove the quotes `'` around the variables. (But @JayBlanchard 's suggestion is still good, error checking means security and finding your errors quickly.)

Comment: Good eye @caCtus, I completely missed that. The OP should have seen those strings in the database and error checking wouldn't have caught that. Off to the coffee pot I go!

Comment: I kinda don't understand that tutorial >_<

Comment: I had $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $passwordHash); but it didn't work so I changed to $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', '$username', '$email', '$passwordHash'); and this does not work either

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting literal strings, your variable names, instead of the values. This will fail after the first time if you have unique constraints:

```
$insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', '$username', '$email', '$passwordHash');
```

You need:

```
$insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $passwordHash);
```

Comment: I had $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $passwordHash); but it didn't work so I changed to
$insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', '$username', '$email', '$passwordHash');
 and this does not work either :D

Comment: @Steven Add this to the top of your script and enable error display: `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` Any messages?

Comment: Not even a one error message... that's weird... that's why I'm posting it here... My mind is blown

Comment: @Steven I assume you have commented out the redirects while testing. If not, you should do that as it will avoid you seeing the output of the script.

Comment: I don't know how to do it :/